# Link in form label using route

Tags: symfony

In my registration form i have a checkbox "I accept the terms", and want to link the word "terms" to my terms page.

Is there a way to add a link to a form label, using a route? (preferably without injecting the container in the form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to overwrite the twig block used to render that specific label.

First, check the [form fragment naming](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-template-blocks) section of the docs. Then create a new block in your form template with the the appropriate name. Don't forget to tell twig to use it:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

For the next step check the [default `form_label` block](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/1ab11c239ac1894837a277e1bd0cdde8fa245da5/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L260).

You'll probably only need a portion of it, something like this (I'm leaving the default block name here):

```
{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
        <a href="{{ path("route_for_terms") }}">{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</a>
    </label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is looking very good, but i don't seem to be able to limit this to just the one label i need it for (i have 2 checkboxes in this one form). I render it with this code: {{ form_row(form.termsAccepted) }}

Comment: See [How to customize an Individual field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field). Assuming your form is named *form*, the block name would be `_form_termsAccepted_label`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your help. I had this problem in the back of my head for a long time, but it never occured to me that it could be solved using twig that easily.

Answer (score 7):

[In Symfony 5.1 there are new form improvements.](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-form-improvements)

[HTML contents are allowed in form labels!](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-form-improvements#allow-html-contents-in-form-labels)

HTML contents are escaped by default in form labels for security reasons. The new label_html boolean option allows a form field to include HTML contents in their labels, which is useful to display icons inside buttons, links and some formatting in checkbox/radiobutton labels, etc.

```
// src/Form/Type/TaskType.php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => ' Save',
                'label_html' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

In your case you can set form label directly from template and pass the route there.

```
{{ form_widget(form.acceptTermsAndConditions, {
    label: '<a href="' ~ path("route") ~ '">' ~ "I accept ..."|trans ~ '</a>',
    label_html: true
    })
}}
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Good that these questions are updated with answers for newer versions of Symfony

Answer (score 6):

As the solution above somehow didn't work for me I solved it using the solution suggested here: https://gist.github.com/marijn/4137467

OK, so here i how I did it:

```
    {% set terms_link %}<a title="{% trans %}Read the General Terms and Conditions{% endtrans %}" href="{{ path('get_general_terms_and_conditions') }}">{% trans %}General Terms and Conditions{% endtrans %}</a>{% endset %}
{% set general_terms_and_conditions %}{{ 'I have read and accept the %general_terms_and_conditions%.'|trans({ '%general_terms_and_conditions%': terms_link })|raw }}{% endset %}
<div>
{{ form_errors(form.acceptGeneralTermsAndConditions) }}

{{ form_widget(form.acceptGeneralTermsAndConditions) }}
<label for="{{ form.acceptGeneralTermsAndConditions.vars.id }}">{{ general_terms_and_conditions|raw }}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

As an option, you can do so:

```
->add('approve', CheckboxType::class, [
    'label' => 'Text part without link',
    'help' => 'And <a href="/x.pdf">download it</a>',
    'help_html' => true,
])
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was another:

form:

```
$builder
->add(
    'agree_to_rules',
    'checkbox',
    [
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'i_agree_to'
    ]
);
```

And html:

```
<span style="display:inline-block">
    {{ form_widget(form.agree_to_rules) }}
</span>
<span style="display:inline-block">
        <a href="#">rules</a>
</span>
```

And looks the same :)

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way to do it would be

```
{{ form_widget(form.terms, { 'label': 'I accept the <a href="'~path('route_to_terms')~'">terms and conditions</a>' }) }}
```

You can also do this if you want to use translation

In your translation file for example messages.en.yml add

```
terms:
    url: 'I accept the <a href="%url%">terms and conditions</a>'
```

And in your view add

```
{{ form_widget(form.terms, { 'label': 'terms.url'|trans({'%url%': path('route_to_terms')}) }) }}
```

Comment: It would be great, unfortunately the html tags are escaped, even if I add |raw filter